# Why use NVL in WHERE clause (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, nvl

I am repeatedly seeing queries similar to:

```
select count(*) 
from some_table
where nvl(some_column,'N') = 'Y';
```

Where `some_column` takes values in `('Y', 'N', null)`.

Is there a reason this is being used rather than the following?

```
select count(*) 
from some_table
where some_column = 'Y';
```

From the few examples I've tried, there doesn't seem to be any performance advantage, and in a few cases the first query being slower.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Used the way you show it, adding `nvl` in the `where` clause makes no sense. What may make some sense, sometimes, is to have a condition like `nvl(some_column, 'Y') = 'Y'` - so that `NULL` are counted the same as `'Y'`.

Comment: As long as you know `NULL = 'Y` return `unknow` and sql treat `unknow` as false you wont need nvl in that case.  The only reason I can think is for show the field can be null to add some clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this a lot too. Most likely the developer has got into the habit of wrapping nullable columns in an `nvl` expression, probably after being burned in the past by an unexpected null value, and now adds it everywhere without bothering to think it through, or perhaps without having really understood the issue in the first place.

This will prevent use of any index, partition pruning or histograms on the underlying column (although the optimiser's adaptive features may generate dynamic histograms to correct for this).

You may need this kind of construction in the case where you are checking that an expression does **not** have some particular value, if you want to treat null as not 'Y' for example. Perhaps the developer is thinking of this.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Is it the same case for when it is used in a procedure like IF NVL ( variable, 'N' ) = 'Y'   THEN ...

Comment: Yes. I came across a whole load of these just today like `case when nvl(somecol,'Y') = 'N' then ...` Of course this is the same thing as `case when somecol = 'N'`, without any `nvl`.